# Flutter Gridview expansion?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

GridView Expansion I have developed this type of Gridview.
When I click the first grid It will return some list between the first and second column widget.
How to achieve this type of expansion when selected the each grid it will expand and return some list. when grid is not selected expansion will false
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int checkedIndex = -1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: 9,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              bool checked = index == checkedIndex;
              return InkWell(
                onTap: (() {
                 
                  setState(() {
                    checkedIndex = index;
                  });
                }),
                child: Container(
                  margin: checked ? EdgeInsets.zero : EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: checked
                          ? Border.all(color: Colors.cyan)
                          : Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Text(
                          "Gift",
                          style: TextStyle(height: 2),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          ),
                          height: 75,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Image.asset("assets/box.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that you;ve tried so far and will reproduce the same issue you are facing?

Comment: code added @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: Can you explain little more about *grid It will return some list between the first and second column widget* and are you trying select multiple grid?

Comment: When like example when I click the the first grid Gift it will show the list of gift items ,then select second Games show the games list below the column. e.g https://sendgb.com/4XjOFyp2RJ3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This UI behavior isn't quit suit for gridView IMO. To do custom UI, I am using row for render item and wrapped row item with Column so that It can show another List bellow it.

**UI Logic**

while our ui will have 3 item per row if we use listView to build item, total itemCount will be

```dart
   itemCount = itemCount ~/ 3 + (itemCount % 3 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Next thing comes on handling tap event and while `index` is provided by `ListView.builder` and to render row item logic will be

```dart
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int renderedItem = itemCount - index * 3;
                        int ri = renderedItem > 3 ? 3 : renderedItem;
```

Selecting single item, where `j` is row item count

```dart
checkedIndex=  j + (index * 3);
```

and showing expanded list logic will be

```dart
if (checkedIndex > -1 &&
    index <= checkedIndex / 3 &&
    index > (checkedIndex / 3) - 1)
```

Logic seems a little bit complicated , someone may narrow it to simpler form, feel free to update/post the answer.

---

**Widget to play with**

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=42f9d0fd68711be6d9a8926c218691ca)

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int checkedIndex = -1;

  int itemCount = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          body: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              final Size itemSize = Size(
                constraints.maxWidth / 3,
                constraints.maxWidth / 3,
              );

              int customGridItemRC =
                  itemCount ~/ 3 + (itemCount % 3 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text("IC: $itemCount"),
                  Slider(
                      max: 33,
                      value: itemCount * 1.0,
                      onChanged: (v) {
                        setState(() {
                          itemCount = v.toInt();
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: customGridItemRC,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int renderedItem = itemCount - index * 3;
                        int ri = renderedItem > 3 ? 3 : renderedItem;
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: List.generate(
                                ri,
                                (j) => GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      int tappedItem = j + (index * 3);
                                      checkedIndex = checkedIndex == tappedItem
                                          ? -1
                                          : tappedItem;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    width: itemSize.width,
                                    height: itemSize.height,
                                    color: checkedIndex == j + (index * 3)
                                        ? Colors.cyanAccent
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                    child: Text("${(index * 3) + j}"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //* extra item list
                            if (checkedIndex > -1 &&
                                index <= checkedIndex / 3 &&
                                index > (checkedIndex / 3) - 1)
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.purple,
                                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    ...List.generate(
                                        3,
                                        (index) => Text(
                                            "THis item is under section $checkedIndex"))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```